# Как сделать всплывающее окно с сообщением (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, python-telegram-bot

Подскажите, как вызвать всплывающее окно в телеграм боте (как на картинке ниже). Окно должно появится в ответ на нажатие пользователем inline кнопки.

Код пишу на Python с библиотекой **python-telegram-bot.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пробовала такие варианты:**

1. `context.answer_callback_query(text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!')` Выводит ошибку `AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'answer_callback_query'`
2. `update.answer_callback_query(text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!')` Выводит ошибку `AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'answer_callback_query'`
3. `bot.answer_callback_query(text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!')` (знаю, что так используют для PyTelegramBotAPI). Ошибка: `NameError: name 'bot' is not defined`
4. `query.answer_callback_query(text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!')` Выводит ошибку `AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'answer_callback_query'`

```
def on_select_date(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global text_data
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    bot = context.bot

    selected, date = telegramcalendar.process_calendar_selection(bot, update)
    if not selected:
        return ConversationHandler.END

    user_data = context.user_data
    text_data = date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    user_data['Дата'] = text_data

    keyboard = [[
        InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("14:30", callback_data='14'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("16:00", callback_data='16')
    ]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    query.message.reply_text(text='''Вы выбрали %s
Выберите свободное время: ''' % text_data, reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return STATE_SELECT_TIME

def check(date: str, time: str):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE data_time = %s"
    var = (data_time, )
    mycursor.execute(sql, var)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
    return myresult

@run_async
@log_func(log)
def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    global text_time
    global data_time

    user_data = context.user_data

    text_time = '12:00'
    user_data['Время'] = text_time

    data_time = text_data + text_time

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    if check(user_data['Дата'], user_data['Время']):
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
        print('Найдено в бд')
    else:
        query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
        return STATE_SELECT_USER

def main():
    # Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(
        token=TOKEN,
        use_context=True
    )

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', on_main_menu))

    dp.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler('start', on_main_menu),
            CallbackQueryHandler(on_sing_up, pattern='sing_up')
        ],
        states={
            STATE_SELECT_TIME: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_12, pattern='12'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_14, pattern='14'),
                CallbackQueryHandler(on_time_16, pattern='16')
            ],

            STATE_SELECT_USER: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_sing_name)
            ]
        },
        fallbacks=[

        ]
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Нашла решение проблемы**

```
def on_time_12(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    # query.answer() <--- эту строку нужно перенести в else

    if check(user_data['Дата'], user_data['Время']):
        query.bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
    else:
        query.answer()
        query.edit_message_text('''Введите своё *Имя и Фамилию*''', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

`query.answer()` нужно перенести в `else:`, чтобы не мешала работе всплывающего окна

Answer (score 2):

Ошибки говорят полезные вещи, нужно вызывать метод `answer_callback_query` у `bot`, но чтобы достать это поле, нужно обратиться к `context`.

```
context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='Извините, это время занято, выберите другое!', show_alert=True)
```

Comment: Попробовала ваш вариант. Но ничего не происходит, ошибок не выводит, бот просто молчит.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос полный код метода, в котором вы используете эту строку